# batch size is not NOT DIVISIBLE under multiple GPU with tensorflow2

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I use custom training with tf.distribute.Strategy in tensorflow2.4.1 (like that https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training?hl=en), I want to know is there any fault if the batch size is not divisible.

Specifically, assuming that the dataset has 14 examples, I have 2 GPUs and set the batch size 4, so the training size is ((2,2), (2,2), (2,2), (1,1)).

If I define the loss by

> tf.nn.compute_average_loss(per_example_loss, global_batch_size=4),

the loss of last batch will be divided by 4, but it only has 2 examples.

Comment: From [Tensorflow document](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training#define_the_loss_function) ,it says Batch_size is multiple of GPU's. `For an example, let's say you have 4 GPU's and a batch size of 64. One batch of input is distributed across the replicas (4 GPUs), each replica getting an input of size 16.`.